# Are there any problems with this Haskell function for strictly timing a computation?

Tags: haskell

Recently I was trying to determine the time needed to calculate a waveform using the vector storage type.

I wanted to do so without requiring to print the length or something like that.  Finally I came up with the following two definitions.  It seems simple enough, and from what I can tell it prints a non-zero computation time as expected the first time I run the function, but I'm wondering if there are any laziness caveats here that I've missed.

```
import System.IO
import System.CPUTime
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as V

timerIO f = do
  start <- getCPUTime
  x <- f
  let !y = x
  end <- getCPUTime
  let diff = (fromIntegral (end - start)) / (10^12)
  print $ "Computation time: " ++ show diff ++ " sec\n"

timer f = timerIO $ do return f

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let sr = 1000.0
      time = V.map (/ sr) $ V.enumFromN 0 120000 :: V.Vector Float
      wave = V.map (\x -> sin $ x * 2 * pi * 10) time :: V.Vector Float

  timer wave
  timer wave
```

prints,

```
Computation time: 0.16001 sec
Computation time: 0.0 sec
```

Are there any hidden bugs here?  I'm really not sure that the `let` with strictness flag is really the best way to go here.  Is there a more concise way to write this?  Are there any standard functions that already do this that I should know about?

Edit: I should mention that I had read about criterion but in this case I was not looking for a robust way to calculate average timing for profiling-only purposes; rather I was looking for a simple / low-overhead way to integrate single timers into my program for tracing the timing of some computations during normal running of the application.  Criterion is cool, but this was a slightly different use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If evaluating to weak head normal form is enough - for strict `Vector`s or `UArray`s it is -, then your timing code works well¹, however, instead of the bang pattern in the let-binding, you could put a bang on the monadic bind,

```
start <- getCPUTime
!x <- f
end <- getCPUTime
```

which to me looks nicer, or you could use `Control.Exception.evaluate`

```
start <- getCPUTime
evaluate f
end <- getCPUTime
```

which has the advantage of (supposed) portability, whereas bang patterns are a GHC extension. If WHNF is not enough, you would need to force full evaluation, for example using `rnf` or `deepseq`, like

```
start <- getCPUTime
!x <- rnf `fmap` f
end <- getCPUTime
```

However, repeatedly timing the same computation with that is hairy. If, as in your example, you give the thing a name, and call it

```
timer wave
timer wave
```

the compiler shares the computation, so it's only done once and all but the first `timer` calls return zero (or *very close* to zero) times. If you call it with code instead of a name,

```
timer (V.map (\x -> sin $ x * 2 * pi * 10) time :: V.Vector Float)
timer (V.map (\x -> sin $ x * 2 * pi * 10) time :: V.Vector Float)
```

the compiler can still share the computation, if it does common subexpression elimination. And although GHC doesn't do much CSE, it does some and I'm rather confident it would spot and share this (when compiling with optimisations). To reliably make the compiler repeat the computations, you need to hide the fact that they are the same from it (or use some low-level internals), which is not easy to do without influencing the time needed for the computation.

¹ It works well if the computation takes a significant amount of time. If it takes only a short time, the jitter introduced by outside influences (CPU load, scheduling, ...) will make single timings far too unreliable. Then you should do multiple measurements, and for that, as has been mentioned elsewhere, the [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) library is an excellent way to relieve you of the burden of writing robust timing code.

Comment: Thank you! The reason for the `let` is that I tried do add a bang to the monad bind, but it didn't seem to be permitted by the compiler.  However, I see that it was because I got the syntax wrong (bang is on the other side of the variable), so thanks for the tip.

Comment: Oops, typo. The bang goes before the variable, `!x <- f`.

Comment: Strange, I get "Illegal bang pattern (use -XBangPatterns)" when I put `!x <- f`.  (And yes, `x! <- f` didn't work either.)  I'm using GHC 7.0.4.

Comment: Of course you need to enable bang patterns, put `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}` at the top of the module. (Or pass `-XBangPatterns` on the command line, but you can't forget the pragma as easily when you recompile.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with [the `deepseq` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq)? It's used by [the `criterion` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) for pretty much the purpose you describe.

Speaking of which, you may want to consider whether `criterion` itself does what you need anyway.

Comment: Speaking of `criterion`, anyone doing any benchmarking should really be using it.

Comment: I am not that impressed by criterion, in all cases I tested it delivered the same results than System.CPUTime except that the criterion results contained a lot of information about deviations etc. that I did not need.

Comment: @JFritsch In my experience, `System.CPUTime` is good for things taking upwards of around 100ms, maybe 20ms, but for short-running tasks it shows too much variation, and it's more convenient to let criterion do the averaging.

Comment: @J Fritsch If you only need CPUTime, of course you won't be impressed. But deviation _is_ useful, so is the density plot rather than the times plot... If you have a weird result then the average time can actually be misleading (ie, two separated extrema)